# Logic Error in Most Common Letter Finder

Tags: python, logic

So, this program simply lets the user enter a string, and counts the occurrence of each character, then displayed the most frequent.

I enter "AABBCCC", and it tells me that the max is 7, and that the most frequent is "Q".

```
countList = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 \
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 \
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 \
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 \
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
index = 0
for character in userInput:
    if character == "Q" or "q":
        countList[0] += 1
    elif character == "W" or "w":
        countList[1] += 1
    elif character == "E" or "e":
        countList[2] += 1
    elif character == "R" or "r":
        countList[3] += 1
    elif character == "T" or "t":
        countList[4] += 1
    elif character == "Y" or "y":
        countList[5] += 1
    elif character == "U" or "u":
        countList[6] += 1
    elif character == "I" or "i":
        countList[7] += 1
    elif character == "O" or "o":
        countList[8] += 1
    elif character == "P" or "p":
        countList[9] += 1
    elif character == "A" or "a":
        countList[10] += 1
    elif character == "S" or "s":
        countList[11] += 1
    elif character == "D" or "d":
        countList[12] += 1
    elif character == "F" or "f":
        countList[13] += 1
    elif character == "G" or "g":
        countList[14] += 1
    elif character == "H" or "h":
        countList[15] += 1
    elif character == "J" or "j":
        countList[16] += 1
    elif character == "K" or "k":
        countList[17] += 1
    elif character == "L" or "l":
        countList[18] += 1
    elif character == "Z" or "z":
        countList[19] += 1
    elif character == "X" or "x":
        countList[20] += 1
    elif character == "C" or "c":
        countList[21] += 1
    elif character == "V" or "v":
        countList[22] += 1
    elif character == "B" or "b":
        countList[23] += 1
    elif character == "N" or "n":
        countList[24] += 1
    elif character == "M" or "m":
        countList[25] += 1
    elif character == "`":
        countList[26] += 1
    elif character == "~":
        countList[27] += 1
    elif character == "1":
        countList[28] += 1
    elif character == "!":
        countList[29] += 1
    elif character == "2":
        countList[30] += 1
    elif character == "@":
        countList[31] += 1
    elif character == "3":
        countList[32] += 1
    elif character == "#":
        countList[33] += 1
    elif character == "4":
        countList[34] += 1
    elif character == "$":
        countList[35] += 1
    elif character == "5":
        countList[36] += 1
    elif character == "%":
        countList[37] += 1
    elif character == "6":
        countList[38] += 1
    elif character == "^":
        countList[39] += 1
    elif character == "7":
        countList[40] += 1
    elif character == "&":
        countList[41] += 1
    elif character == "8":
        countList[42] += 1
    elif character == "*":
        countList[43] += 1
    elif character == "9":
        countList[44] += 1
    elif character == "(":
        countList[45] += 1
    elif character == "0":
        countList[46] += 1
    elif character == ")":
        countList[47] += 1
    elif character == "-":
        countList[48] += 1
    elif character == "_":
        countList[49] += 1
    elif character == "=":
        countList[50] += 1
    elif character == "+":
        countList[51] += 1
    elif character == "[":
        countList[52] += 1
    elif character == "{":
        countList[53] += 1
    elif character == "]":
        countList[54] += 1
    elif character == "}":
        countList[55] += 1
    elif character == "\\":
        countList[56] += 1
    elif character == "|":
        countList[57] += 1
    elif character == ";":
        countList[58] += 1
    elif character == ":":
        countList[59] += 1
    elif character == "'":
        countList[60] += 1
    elif character == "\"":
        countList[61] += 1
    elif character == ",":
        countList[62] += 1
    elif character == "<":
        countList[63] += 1
    elif character == ".":
        countList[64] += 1
    elif character == ">":
        countList[65] += 1
    elif character == "/":
        countList[66] += 1
    elif character == "?":
        countList[67] += 1
mostFrequent = max(countList)
print(mostFrequent)
characterKey = ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "A" \
, "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M" \
, "`", "~", "1", "!", "2", "@", "3", "#", "4", "$", "5", "%", "6", "^", "7" \
, "&", "8", "*", "9", "(", "0", ")", "-", "_", "=", "+", "[", "{", "]", "}" \
, "\\", "|", ";", ":", "'", "\"", ",", "<", ".", ">", "/", "?"]

index = 0
for character in countList:
    if character == mostFrequent:
        print(characterKey[index], "is most frequent.")
    index += 1
```

Comment: `or` doesn't work the way you think it does. Most common Python error ever.

Comment: @MarkRansom is right. im sure you choose a really long way to do it. but anyway the `or` should looks like that `character == "Z" or character == "z":`

Comment: @MikeW I believe in this case the title is probably accurate, making your request futile.

Comment: @Mark With all due respect, this person is a beginner, and "most common python error ever" is not the most welcoming way to deal with their issue. I appreciate that Or Duan is taking the time to actually provide an answer, but it would be nice to see a more friendly approach from you as well. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @BlueIce of course you're right, I guess I'm just in a weird mood tonight. I expected "most common Python error ever" to trigger someone to find a duplicate of this question. The second comment was just a lame attempt at being funny - I could see how this would drive someone batty.

Comment: @MarkRansom I gotcha, no worries :) I hope you feel better and I'll see you around the site.

Comment: I'm up-voting this question, because it's been super down-voted. Sure, maybe a -1 for a bad title, but seriously -5? The problem is defined, the person made an attempt, and has essentially a minimal reproducible example (granted you need to add one string, but that is trivial).

Answer (score 2):

One of the issues that you are dealing with is that

```
elif character == "T" or "t"
```

does not work the way you think it does. You must restate the left-handed side of the expression again, like this:

```
elif character == "T" or character == "t"
```

or you can use the `in` operator:

```
elif character in ("T,"t")
```

However, changing this is not going to completely fix your issue.

One thing that would help your code be cleaner and faster would be to look into translating the character value that you receive into an integer value, and then using the integer value as a means of putting the character into the right index of the array. I'll leave that exercise to you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of a dict would save you some code. .lower() can prevent you having to check each as I'm assuming that for your puposes 't is eqivalent to 'T'. Note that helper function is expecting a string that is not Null. Hope this can help

```
def get_character_frequency(user_input):
    '''return dictionary of frequencies to characters'''  

    char_freq_dict = {}
    freq_char_dict = {}
    #create dict with characters as keys and freqs as values
    for character in user_input:
        char_freq_dict[character] = char_freq_dict.get(character, 0) + 1
    #invert dict
    for character, freq in char_freq_dict.items():
        if freq in freq_char_dict.keys():
            freq_char_dict[freq].append(character)
        else:
            freq_char_dict[freq] = [character]
    return freq_char_dict

def main():
    #you could add some code to ensure some text is entered, or 
    #modify to error check for this

    userInput = input("Enter String: ").lower()
    freq_char_dict = get_character_frequency(userInput)         
    max_freq, max_char = sorted(freq_char_dict.items(), reverse=1)[0]
    print('\n{} characters were entered'.format(len(userInput)))    
    print('Most frequent character(s) {}'.format(max_char), end="  ")
    print('Ocurring {} time(s)'.format(max_freq))

main()
```

Comment: Im in the summer Python class and dictionaries are not for this chapter LOL. I am doing lists/tuples and strings this week

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
import re
import itertools
import operator

def most_common(L):
  # get an iterable of (item, iterable) pairs
  SL = sorted((x, i) for i, x in enumerate(L))
  # print 'SL:', SL
  groups = itertools.groupby(SL, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
  # auxiliary function to get "quality" for an item
  def _auxfun(g):
    item, iterable = g
    count = 0
    min_index = len(L)
    for _, where in iterable:
      count += 1
      min_index = min(min_index, where)
    # print 'item %r, count %r, minind %r' % (item, count, min_index)
    return count, -min_index
  # pick the highest-count/earliest item
  return max(groups, key=_auxfun)[0]

user_input = [_.lower() for _ in raw_input("Enter String: ")]
frequent = most_common(list(user_input))
print "Most frequent entry:",frequent
print "Number of Occerences:",user_input.count(frequent)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter String: aAbBBcccC12309u/.,;'/*
Most frequent entry: c
Number of Occerences: 4
```